# Can i to implement a menu in the appBar using flutter_webview_plugin?

Tags: webview, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I need to implement a menu in the application bar and also show a webview at the same time

I'm using:
-Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2
-Android SDK version 28.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, use an AppBar and then show de WebView.

PS: This AppBar has nothing to do with the WebView itself

**UPDATE**

Example:

```
Scaffold(
 appBar: AppBar(),
 drawer: Drawer(),
 body: WebView()
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm using the flutter_webview_plugin library and I wanted to know if it was possible to implement the menu with that library, since I've only seen that the library allows an appBar but not a menu within it.I use this library because it allows me to use the keyboard inside the webview

Comment: OK, you want to display a menu in a AppBar, right? Check this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer

Comment: Thanks dude, but that doesn't work in my case, since the `flutter_webview_plugin` library has its own `WebViewScaffold` and this doesn't allow using the **Drawer** widget. Likewise, thank you very much, if you know of any WebView library that allows me to use a menu in my AppBar and use the keyboard inside the WebView at same time, it'll help me a lot.

Comment: There is, the Flutter Team's webview: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter. Works like another Widget, thats why made answers is written like this, now, since you want a drawer, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks, I have been working with that Widget and it allows me to have a menu in the AppBar but it doesn't let me use the keyboard in the WebView, I will be working with that library and if I can make the keyboard work, I will comment it here. Thanks again for your feedback. :)